# Email Masking FreeFrom pro

Tags: solspace-freeform, email, email-contact-form

I am using Freeform pro with a EE site that sells classified goods. I have a form where the customer can email another customer/member. But id like to mask the email with sender and receiver something like gumtree or craigslist. Can someone suggest a method for this if its possible.

Thank,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to run some custom software that integrated with a local mail server to do this - beyond the scope of even an EE add-on I'd say, because your mail server would need to know how to map the incoming email aliases to your site members.

Maybe there's a third-party service that lets you create forwarding addresses programmatically via an API? That would be your best bet, if it exists - then you'd just need to store that anonymous email address as a custom member field for each member.

Comment: Thanks @Derek is this something that would be of use to what your saying? http://mask.it

Comment: Yes, exactly something like that - looks promising.